# Equivalent of "doch" (German) or "jo" (Norwegian) in Spanish dialects

Tags: traducción, vocabulario, coloquialismos

**English**

There's a very useful word in German, Norwegian and other languages that's used to respond to negative questions in a way that the contrary of the question is expressed. Example:

> - Hast du keinen Namen? (Don't you have a name?)
>   - Doch! (I do!)

In Guatemalan Spanish there is an equivalent, namely *bien*, used in colloquial speech and normally frowned upon (regarded as incorrect by many, yay presctivism) when used in that sense, and I was wondering if other Spanish dialects feature such a word.

**Español**

En alemán existe una palabra muy útil que se utiliza para responder a preguntas negativas expresando el contrario de la oración. Por ejemplo:

> - Hast du keinen Namen? (¿No tienes nombre?)
>   - Doch! (¡Sí lo tengo!)

En español guatemalteco existe un equivalente: *bien*, usada generalmente en lenguaje coloquial y vista mal por muchas personas (yay, prescriptivismo) cuando se utiliza en ese sentido. Me preguntaba si existe algún equivalente en otros dialectos.

Thanks/Gracias

Comment: ¿Este uso guatamalteco está recogido en algún sitio?  El DRAE solo tiene una única acepción para *bien* como respuesta a preguntas y es para indicar acuerdo (donde usaría un español *vale*) y el DPD no desaconseja tal uso (ni lo menciona).  Yo creo que en España lo equivalente sería «que sí»

Comment: ¿Son _Doch_ y _Jo_ onomatopeyas para responder sí a una pregunta negativa?

Comment: @guifa hasta donde yo sé, nadie ha registrado ese uso guatemalteco. Seguramente por el estigma de usarlo (la gente lo considera incorrecto tristemente).

Comment: @David, onomatopeyas de qué sonidos?

Comment: @clinch Onomapoteyas de este [estilo](http://jackmoreno.wordpress.com/2013/06/08/onomatopeyas/), es decir, que la persona responde sí (_Doch_ o _Jo_) con un sonido que es descrito por esa palabra o son palabras como _si_ en francés que tienen la función que ud. describe.

Comment: @David no, no son onomatopeyas. Son palabras que tienen otros usos en otros contextos también. Al igual que el _bien_ en el español guatemalteco.

Answer (score 5):

No existe un equivalente en español para eso. Realmente, *doch* es algo que tienen en alemán pero en español -yo te hablo de, al menos, español de España- no lo tenemos. (Omito tu apunte sobre el dialecto guatemalteco porque no lo conozco y además es algo muy localizado.)

¿Qué hacemos entonces? Es algo muy relativo y no sé si podríamos poner una norma. Veamos cómo nos las apañamos sin el *doch* con algunos ejemplos:

1. -¿No coges el ascensor? -No, subiré por escaleras, gracias.
2. -Hace un día muy bonito, ¿no crees? -Sí, lástima que tenga faena en casa.
3. -Hace un día muy bonito, ¿no crees? -No, con este sol ¡hace un calor espantoso!
4. -Tienes frío, ¿no es así? -No, tengo calor.
5. -Tienes frío, ¿no? -Sí, ¿ponemos la calefacción?
6. -¿No tienes frío? -No, para nada.
7. -¿No te gusta mi regalo? -No, qué va, ¡me encanta!
8. -¿No te gusta mi regalo? -Qué va, ¡me encanta!
9. -¿No te gusta mi regalo? -¡Qué dices! ¡Pero si es perfecto!
10. -¿No te gusta mi regalo? -No, la verdad es que no mucho...
11. -¿No quieres más? -¡Sí, sí! Ponme un poco más, por favor.
12. -¿No quieres más? -No, estoy lleno, gracias.
13. -¿No tendrías unas entradas para mi amigo? -Sí, me han sobrado dos, aquí tienes.
14. -¿No tienes más que esos ejemplares? -No, en la trastienda tengo más.
15. -¿No tienes más que esos ejemplares? -Sí, en la trastienda tengo más.
16. -¿No tienes más que esos ejemplares? -Pues no, esta semana es todo lo que hay.
17. -¿No me dijiste que no querías venir? -No, yo no dije tal cosa.

Como ves, es muy relativo... Podríamos establecer una protonorma, que contaría con varias excepciones no regladas:

- Caso (A). Preguntas del tipo: ¿No + verbo + complementos? Son equivalentes a: ¿Verbo + complementos?
  Ejemplos:
  -¿No coges el ascensor?
  -¿No tienes frío?

Excepción: *¿No tienes más que esos ejemplares?* Una respuesta como: *No, en la trastienda tengo más.* tiene cabida, aun siendo también posible: *[Pues] No, esta semana es todo lo que hay.*

La primera respuesta niega la negación de la pregunta -o sea, negamos la totalidad de la pregunta-, mientras que la segunda respuesta niega la pregunta sin el *no* -o sea, como si siquiera la norma. La primera respuesta podría venir acompañada de una pronunciación que reforzara el *no*, marcando que negamos la pregunta en su totalidad. Pero ha de venir con una aclaración después: si respondiéramos sólo *No.* estaríamos diciendo que en efecto no hay más ejemplares que los que se ven.

- Caso (B). Preguntas del tipo: [Enunciado], ¿no? Equivalen a ¿no crees que [enunciado]? E iríamos al caso (A) para encontrar la regla a aplicar.

Ejemplos:
Hace frío, ¿no?

---

De las preguntas 7 a 10:

7. -¿No te gusta mi regalo? -No, qué va, ¡me encanta!
8. -¿No te gusta mi regalo? -Qué va, ¡me encanta!
9. -¿No te gusta mi regalo? -¡Qué dices! ¡Pero si es perfecto!
10. -¿No te gusta mi regalo? -No, la verdad es que no mucho...

He puesto los ejemplos 7 y 8 para mostrar la equivalencia que hay entre *No, qué va* y *Qué va*, lo cual pone de manifiesto una excepción a la norma del caso (A). Con un *No, qué va* negamos la totalidad de lo "enunciado" en la pregunta. Se dice con énfasis en la pronunciación. Viene a significar: *Te equivocas por completo en la suposición expresada implícitamente en tu pregunta: tu regalo me encanta.*

El ejemplo 9 ilustra que *¡Qué dices!* tiene el mismo significado que *Qué va*.

El ejemplo 10 sigue la norma del caso (A).

Lo que pasa es que, claro, preguntar con un *no* delante no es lo mismo que sin; al hacerlo expresamos implícitamente una suposición y se le da otro matiz a la pregunta y al diálogo.

---

El ejemplo 11:

11. -¿No quieres más? -¡Sí, sí! Ponme un poco más, por favor.

De hecho, en el ejemplo 11 la respuesta es *¡Sí, sí!* Y no *¡Sí!* porque el doble *sí* enfatiza que estamos negando la presuposición de la pregunta. O sea, es como los ejemplos 7, 8 y 9. En el ejemplo 11 no tendría sentido responder un sólo *sí*: si es que no queremos más, respondemos *No.*, siquiendo la norma del caso (A). Si, al contrario de lo presupuesto, sí queremos más -nótese que he recalcado el sentido afirmativo-, entonces debemos remarcarlo, señalando que la presuposición es errónea y negamos la totalidad de la pregunta; esto responde a una excepción de la norma del caso (A).

La pregunta 11 es casi equivalente a esta otra: *-No quieres más, ¿verdad?*, la cual puede responderse con:

- *Sí, quiero más*. Aclaramos necesariamente, tras el *sí*, la respuesta.
- *No, no, gracias*. Repetimos el *no* para suavizarlo, que no quede tajante, dado que la presuposición en la pregunta es correcta.

Este último ejemplo muestra lo relativo que es todo y que aún se pueden añadir más ejemplos, más casos y más excepciones.

---

Este tema me resulta la mar de interesante. Da la casualidad de que esta cuestión ya la he hablado varias veces con un buen colega mío que ha estado varios años viviendo en Alemania. Él normalmente responde con un chistoso *jein* -de *ja*+*nein*- a las preguntas de este tipo que nos llevan a un diálogo de besugos, lo cual se sigue de unas risas y de una discusión acerca de la respuesta más adecuada en español -o *correcta* en nuestras pretensiones.

Comment: @ Paloma: hola, soy aleman. Es una pregunta muy interesante también para otros lenguajes. Pero tengo que decir que para mi solo tus ejemplos 7. - 11. y 14. - 15. suenan correcto. El uso más habitual en aleman sería p.ej. "No me quieres más, verdad? - Doch, ich liebe Dich noch." Para entender mejor los diferentes significados en aleman recomendo ver los ejemplos del enlace: http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/doch_Adverb

Answer (score 1):

Podrías usar *Claro que sí*.

> - ¿No vienes con nosotros?
>   - Claro que sí, ¡vengo!